# SwiftUI accent color in dark mode not displayed correctly

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've defined a custom accent color for light and dark mode. When using light mode the accent color should be black and in dark mode white.

When using light mode everything works fine:

[image: When light mode is active]

But when turning dark appearance on, the selection color for the list item isn't working as expected.

[image: When dark mode is active]

What am I missing? Why does the selection not invert in dark mode? The provided screenshots are related to the simulator in macOS.

Many thanks!

Update:
As asked by @son the code for the selection

```
List(selection: $appState.selectedDetail) {                         
  ForEach(listItems) { item in          
    HStack {                             
      Text("\(item.startDate.formatDate())")                             
      Text("-")
      Text("\(item.endDate.formatDate())")                             
    }
    .tag(DetailSelection.item(item: item))                                 
    .monospaced()                
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show code to highlight the row?

Comment: Updated the question with the respective code snippet. But I don't think it's a problem with the code, cause light mode inverts totally fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the [instructions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/specifying-your-apps-color-scheme) for specifying an accent color and it works for me:

[image: Screenshots]

There are two main steps:

1. Configure the color in your asset library:

[image: AccentColor]

2. Name it in your build settings:

[image: BuildSettings]

Comment: Thanks for your verification. Could you please test the color black for appearance dark?

Comment: I changed orange to black in the example above and it works too -> the selected entry is shown using white text on black background (which in fact looks very similar to a non-selected item). If your accent color is partially working then it makes me wonder if you have more than one color in your asset catalog and it is using the wrong one? Perhaps there is a typo somewhere, or your build setting is not set correctly in all places. I think the build target may be able to override the project setting for **Global Accent Color Name**, so best to check both.

Comment: You have to change orange to white to get the same situation as I do, I guess. Because in dark mode the selected item should display with a black text on white background.

Comment: @andreas.teich Well you asked me to test the color black, so I did. If you are setting the dark mode color to white then it's been working all along. The color you control (the background) is white, but unfortunately, the color you don't control (the foreground) is also white, so you can't read the text.

Comment: Yes that's my problem! Sorry for the confusion. You would what I asked for sry about that. Hm...any ideas how to change the foreground color for a selected item or is that not possible at all?

Comment: I think you just have to set the foreground color explcitly, dependent on the color scheme (see other answer) *and* the current selection.

Comment: Okay, so thanks for your time! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

You get the environment color scheme and set the text color according to the current scheme.

```
@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
var body:some View{
   Text("Your Text here")
   .foregroundStyle(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the selected foreground style for a list item too?

Comment: Yess. Change the listStyle too. Set it to .inset or .plain depending of what you are looking for